# You have an error in your SQL syntax; 'by rand() limit 0,5' at line 1

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

```
$sql="select * from ".$this->table;
    $sql.="order by rand() limit 0,10" ;
    return $this->executeQuery($sql);
```

i got an error when i run this query  , I have no idea what is going on

Comment: Please provide the error

Comment: need a space before ` order by`

Comment: When you're having issues with concatenated SQL, it's always useful to print the contents of the variable just before you call `executeQuery` to see what you actually ended up with; that would have solved this problem for you.

Answer (score 0):

Add a space before

```
order by rand() ...
```

Otherwise it will be something like

```
select * from tablenameorder by
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a space between the table name and the ORDER BY clause.

```
$sql="select * from ".$this->table;
    $sql.=" order by rand() limit 0,5" ;
    return $this->executeQuery($sql);
```